# Alpine transition causes elements to 'jump'

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I have a simple card-based 'slide show' using Alpine and Tailwind. I have a `x-transition.opacity` on the elements I want to animate between, but I get a weird 'jump' where the next or previous element pushes the next one down momentarily. My code is here:

```html
<body class="..." x-data="infocards()">
    <div class="...">
        <template x-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index">
            <div x-show="activeCard === index" class="card" x-transition.opacity x-cloak>
                <div class="...">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" class="w-24">
                    <p x-text="card.title" class="..."></p>
                </div>
                <div class="..."></div>
            </div>
        </template>
        <div class="...">
            <template x-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index">
                <span x-bind:class="{ 'text-sky-200': activeCard === index }"  x-on:click="setActiveCard(index)">&bullet;</span>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div class="...">
            <button @click="showCard(-1)" class="...">Back</button>
            <button @click="showCard(1)" class="...">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function infocards() {
            return {
                activeCard: 0,
                cards: [
                    {
                        title: "Find campsites near you",
                        text: "We have a great range of campsites. Many of them have toilets, and all of them have grass."
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Reserve directly from your phone",
                        text: "Our revolutionary app allows you to call our call centre in Tajikistan for just $1 a minute and book your campsite with a short, unintelligible conversation."
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Get directions to the location",
                        text: "Our revolutionary app also allows you to order a wonderful 3x3m map of the approximate area of the campsite. Simple!"
                    },
                ],
                setActiveCard(index) {
                    this.activeCard = index;
                },
                showCard(step) {
                    const newCard = this.activeCard + step;
                    if (newCard >= 0 && newCard < this.cards.length) {
                        this.activeCard = newCard;
                    }
                },
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

It's exactly the same issue shown here on Alpine's github page:

https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/discussions/1561

Which seems to suggest it's fixed. What gives?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Quentin fair enough. I've included the code directly